# How to Fix Object of class LetterGenerator could not be converted to string in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to add a random code for Merchants in my Laravel app, but i've got 2 problem.

1. When i add random generator function in controller app gonna take so much time to response to my request, and nothing gonna happen in Network Browser, but when i refresh my page data is created, but i won't get any response on creating and my request still holding at Pending.
2. Now when i use Global Class for my function I'm getting "Object of class App\Common\NumberGenerator could not be converted to string".

Right now I've looked into other Q/A and they're not similar to my problem, I've tried to use "(string) before value i wanted to get", I've used serialized, and didn't worked. maybe they should work but i'm beginner and I've tried methods base on tutorials... So here's the code for controller and class. I've put simple data in this file.

Controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'gametype' => 'required|string|min:2',
        'description' => 'required|string|min:1|max:180',
        'price' => 'required|numeric|min:4',
        'buyyer_id' => 'required|numeric|min:1'
    ]);

    $VerifyRandomNumber = $this->GetRandNumber(15);
    $requestModel = new RequestModel;
    // store
    $requestModel->title       = $VerifyRandomNumber;
    $requestModel->description      = $request['description'];
    $requestModel->gametype = $request['gametype'];
    $requestModel->price       = $request['price'];
    $requestModel->buyyer_id      = $request['buyyer_id'];
    $requestModel->seller_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $requestModel->save();

    return $this->SendRequestSMS($request['title'], $request['gametype']);


}

public function GetRandNumber($length) {

    $randomNumber = new NumberGenerator($length);
    $randomNumber-> get_rand_numbers();

    return $randomNumber;
}
```

Generator Class :

```
class NumberGenerator
{
private $lenght;

public function __construct($lenght)
{
    $this->lenght = $lenght;
}


/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function assign_rand_value($num) {

    // accepts 1 - 36
    switch($num) {
        case "1"  : $rand_value = "a"; break;
        case "2"  : $rand_value = "b"; break;
        case "3"  : $rand_value = "c"; break;
        case "4"  : $rand_value = "d"; break;
        case "5"  : $rand_value = "e"; break;
        case "6"  : $rand_value = "f"; break;
        case "7"  : $rand_value = "g"; break;
        case "8"  : $rand_value = "h"; break;
        case "9"  : $rand_value = "i"; break;
        case "10" : $rand_value = "j"; break;
        case "11" : $rand_value = "k"; break;
        case "12" : $rand_value = "l"; break;
        case "13" : $rand_value = "m"; break;
        case "14" : $rand_value = "n"; break;
        case "15" : $rand_value = "o"; break;
        case "16" : $rand_value = "p"; break;
        case "17" : $rand_value = "q"; break;
        case "18" : $rand_value = "r"; break;
        case "19" : $rand_value = "s"; break;
        case "20" : $rand_value = "t"; break;
        case "21" : $rand_value = "u"; break;
        case "22" : $rand_value = "v"; break;
        case "23" : $rand_value = "w"; break;
        case "24" : $rand_value = "x"; break;
        case "25" : $rand_value = "y"; break;
        case "26" : $rand_value = "z"; break;
        case "27" : $rand_value = "0"; break;
        case "28" : $rand_value = "1"; break;
        case "29" : $rand_value = "2"; break;
        case "30" : $rand_value = "3"; break;
        case "31" : $rand_value = "4"; break;
        case "32" : $rand_value = "5"; break;
        case "33" : $rand_value = "6"; break;
        case "34" : $rand_value = "7"; break;
        case "35" : $rand_value = "8"; break;
        case "36" : $rand_value = "9"; break;
    }
    return $rand_value;
}


function get_rand_numbers() {
    if ($this->lenght>0) {
        $rand_id="";
        for($i=1; $i<=$this->lenght; $i++) {
            mt_srand((double)microtime() * 1000000);
            $num = mt_rand(27,36);
            $rand_id .= $this->assign_rand_value($num);
        }
    }
    return $rand_id;
}

}
```

Right now i'm totally beginner and trying to learn to do this base on real-world app, there is another class which i'm using on this and it' 'sendsms' which it just take 1sec to send request, and app working fine with function, but when i use this method, i'm getting this problem.

Comment: About problem 1 - It seems this function `SendRequestSMS``is the responsable for the delay. Could you post it?

Comment: @AlbertoGuilherme Yes. the moment i've tried to add NumberGenerator SMS Service Proivder was on repair from data center, and that was the reason of delay and getting fail.

Comment: I`m glad it running ok. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem 2 -
You are return the class and not the string

```
public function GetRandNumber($length) {

    $randomNumber = new NumberGenerator($length);
    $randomNumber-> get_rand_numbers();

    return $randomNumber;
}
```

You need to return the result of the get_rand_numbers(), like this:

```
public function GetRandNumber($length) {

    $randomNumber = new NumberGenerator($length);
    return $randomNumber-> get_rand_numbers();

}
```